# Why is the function defined outside the C++ class not designed like this?

Tags: c++

for example

```
class Book
{
    using sales = size_t;
public:
    sales get();

};
```

we have to add the scoping operator to use the sales.

```
Book::sales Book::get()
{

}
```

Why does the C++ standard not use this way of writing?It looks more concise

```
Book::sales get()
{

}
```

Why doesn't C++ use the scoping operator that precedes the entire function include return value?

Comment: Because you can define a free function that returns a type that's defined in a class scope.  The qualification of a function's return type is totally unrelated to the qualification of the function itself.

Comment: A qualified identifier (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers) only qualifies the identifier, not a block. Your `using sales` line could have been (not saying one or the other way would be better) outside your class. Then only `get` would need `Book::`, whereas free functions using `sales` would need it only for the return type, as @MilesBudnek mentioned.

Comment: You could reference sales from the outside (just for usage) by `using Book::sales;`, then you do not have to qualify it at each occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a second class:

```
class Shop
{
public:
    Book::sales get();
};
```

Which of the two `get` methods would your code sample implement? How would the compiler know that you aren't just trying to define a new free function called `get`?

You have to specify the containing class on the return type because at the point that the compiler parses the return type it doesn't necessarily know that it is parsing a member function of `Book`. You have to specify the class again on the member function name because the return type being a member type doesn't unambiguously indicate that the method is from the same class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use trailing return type to reduce the repetition (C++11):

```
auto Book::get() -> sales {
    /*...*/
};
```

It uses the nesting class (as the most suitable candidate) to qualify the return type - applying scope identifier hiding rules.
As other answers have already discussed, with traditional syntax the return type and member function must be independently qualified.
But trailing return type tries to deduce the return type qualifications from the member function's nesting scope; this feature might break existing code if it were applied to traditional syntax, but with new syntax there is no pre-existing code to be broken in the first place.
This is a less known feature of C++, due to the emergence of return type deduction syntax in C++14:

```
class Book{
public:
    auto get(){
        /*...*/
    };
};
```

Comment: I was thinking  if that was the correct term?! Maybe I should remove it.

Comment: Way better now.